# VS code breakpoints failing to trigger using Debugger for Chrome:

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm new to VS Code (using v1.7) and to JavaScript. I'm trying to use the Debugger for Chrome extension (v2.2.2) but I am unable to get breakpoints to function (I can set them but they are ignored stating unverified breakpoint).

I understand that I need to launch Chrome with debugging on port 9222 which I achieve through:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Having done that I've set up a very simple test to demonstrate the problem.

I've configured the launch.json as follows (in the .vscode folder)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "name": "Launch index.html",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9222,
            "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've created a very simple index.html as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

and finally script.js is:

```
console.log("Started");
var x = 1; //breakpoint set here
console.log(x);
console.log("Complete");
```

Pressing F5 in Code then load index.html running script.js in the process. The code finishes as would be expected if the breakpoint wasn't set - but it's not what I want to happen.

On completion, I see image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1wsM.png) which replaces the red breakpoint icon with a grey one and hovering over shows "Unverified breakpoint".

I imagine I've done something really simple wrong, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your setup is correct, but this is due to a bug in chrome dev tools - [Chrome needs to be refreshed before javascript files are shown in the sources tab](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=637609&can=1&q=dev%20tools%20source%20tab%20script%20not%20showing&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)
What's happening?
After the script executes V8 collects it before the chrome debug extension has started the dev tools. That's why it cannot be debugged.
Solution - **reload the page after it's loaded.**

Comment: That's a bug within the chrome dev tools, @Marcs. If you start the index.html file from above and then open dev tools, you won't find it in the sources tab.

Comment: ... you won't find the script in the sources tabs... For some reason i can't edit or delete my comment above.

Comment: You are correct, same problem on the internal debugger and also on Chrome Canary (beta branch).

Comment: Well that explains a lot! But I'm not sure I've quite understood. So I've launched Chrome as described in my question, then I've pressed F5 to load the page - doesn't work as we know. Then I go to the browser and reload the page, I still don't get Code to stop on the breakpoint. If I go back to Code (having reloaded the page) and restart, it just opens a new tab.

Comment: @MIB also you could have problems if you have more windows or tabs already open, try to close all windows and be sure to stop chrome background process if you have one, be sure not to have any chrome process still running, check the bottom of the info page of Chrome debugger on vscode for more information.